# How to pass a variable to src attribute in HTML img tag

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, image, src

the image in my .aspx file

```
 <img src='<%=vPath%>' alt="" id="image" />
```

in aspx.cs

```
 public string vPath  ;
 protected void BtnSearchFarms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {string vImageName = LblFarmId.Text;

string vPath = "~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg";}
```

how can I pass the vPath variable to src in the img tag?
is it correct? it still doesn't show any result in the img tag when I execute the page

Comment: _When_ do you need it set and therefore also sets when the image will be requested? Based on your code above, you are saying "set it **after** a button click event."..

Answer (score 0):

Not sure exactly what you are trying to achieve or whether you are going about it correctly, but the very simplest, quick and easy way to do this is:

```
<asp:Button id="BtnSearchFarms" OnClientClick="imageToHiddenField()" />
<input type="hidden" name="imgHidden" id="imgHidden" />
```

Then javascript:

```
function imageToHiddenField() {
    document.getElementById("imgHidden").value = document.getElementById("image").src;
}
```

The value will be added to the hidden field and will go back with the posted data. It can be retrieved using Request.QueryString["imgHidden"] or Request.Form["imgHidden"] depending on whether you are using POST or GET.

Not elegant, but it should work.

Comment: finally I found solution for that 
in .aspx
I added runat="server"  to HTML tag
<img runat="server"  alt=" id="image" Width="600"  Height="800" >

in aspx.cs I added

image.Src = vPath;

Now the img tag can view images based on the input of the user

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell from your question but it sounds like you have an image on your page and you're trying to change the src based on user input?

I'd say instead of using `<img>` the easiest way is to use an `<asp:Image>` which then has an ImageUrl property you can set. An ASP Image works generally like a regular img except you can use ~ in your paths.

```
protected void BtnSearchFarms_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string vImageName = LblFarmId.Text;
    theAspImage.ImageUrl = "~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg";
    theAspImage.Visible = true;
}
```

And in the aspx:

```
<asp:Image id="theAspImage" runat="server" Visible="false" />
```

If you can't use an asp:image then you need to resolve the path so it doesn't have a ~. You can use `Page.ResolveUrl("~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg")` which will convert it to a web accessible path.

One important note, very important note, you have `string vPath` inside your event handler. That means you're creating a new variable not modifying your public instance variable. Change:

`string vPath = "~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg";`
To:
`vPath = "~/attachments/survey/" + vImageName + ".jpg";`

If neither of those answer your question, then I think we need more information.

Comment: actually I have used <asp:Image> before in this code, but the purpose of changing it to img HTML code, because I wanted to let the user able to rotate and flip the image (this image is retrieved from the FTP based on the input of the user in the textbox) and I couldn't solve the rotate problem by C#, then I had to use JavaScript and HTML tag

Comment: You can still use JavaScript on an ASP:Image, you just use the ClientID. But in any case, try the Page.ResolveUrl if you want to use an img tag. Also I updated my answer because you're redefining vPath which is making it so the public instance variable is never getting set. Instead you are setting the local variable you created in the method.